# How to combine LabelBinarizer and OneHotEncoder in pipeline in python for categorical variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, preprocessor, feature-extraction

I have looked up for the right tutorials and Q/A on stackoverflow for the last few days without finding the right guide, primarily because examples showing use case of LabelBinarizer or OneHotEncoder don't show how it's incorporated into pipeline, and vice versa.

I have a dataset with 4 variables:

```
num1    num2    cate1    cate2
3       4       Cat      1
9       23      Dog      0
10      5       Dog      1
```

num1 and num2 are numeric variables, cate1 and cate2 are categorical variables. I understand I need to encode the categorical variables somehow before fitting a ML algorithm, but I am not quite sure how to do that in pipeline after multiple tries.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelBinarizer

# Class that identifies Column type
class Columns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, names=None):
        self.names = names
    def fit (self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.names]

# Separate target from training features
y = df['MED']
X = df.drop('MED', axis=1)

X_selected = X.filter(['num1', 'num2', 'cate1', 'cate2'])

# from the selected X, further choose categorical only
X_selected_cat = X_selected.filter(['cate1', 'cate2']) # hand selected since some cat var has value 0, 1

# Find the numerical columns, exclude categorical columns
X_num_cols = X_selected.columns[X_selected.dtypes.apply(lambda c: np.issubdtype(c, np.number))] # list of numeric column names, automated here
X_cat_cols = X_selected_cat.columns # list of categorical column names, previously hand-slected

# Split data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_selected, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.5, 
                                                    random_state=567, 
                                                    stratify=y)

# Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([
    ("features", FeatureUnion([
        ('numeric', make_pipeline(Columns(names=X_num_cols),StandardScaler())),
        ('categorical', make_pipeline(Columns(names=X_cat_cols)))
    ])),
    ('LR_model', LogisticRegression()),
])
```

This gives me error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Cat'`

Replacing the last 4th line with this

```
('categorical', make_pipeline(Columns(names=X_cat_cols),OneHotEncoder()))
```

will give me the same `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Cat'`.

Replacing the last 4th line with this

```
('categorical', make_pipeline(Columns(names=X_cat_cols),LabelBinarizer(),OneHotEncoder()))
])),
```

will give me a different error `TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Replacing the last 4th line with this

```
('numeric', make_pipeline(Columns(names=X_num_cols),LabelBinarizer())),
```

will give me this error `TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Comment: `LabelBinarizer` - transforms your vector into one hot encoded (one-vs-all fashion) matrix. So you don't need OneHotEncoder ...

Comment: Thanks MaxU, I tried only using LabelBinarizer (updated), but it gave me a different error.

Comment: what is `Columns(...)` in your code?

Comment: Added in the code.

Comment: If you can update sklearn to the dev version (which should soon be released), you could have a look at:
[CategoricalEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html)

Answer (score 2):

Taking up on Marcus' suggestion, I tried but unable to install scikit-learn dev version, but have found something similar called [category_encoders](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/category_encoders/1.2.6).

Changing the code into this works:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelBinarizer
import category_encoders as CateEncoder

# Class that identifies Column type
class Columns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, names=None):
        self.names = names
    def fit (self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.names]

# Separate target from training features
y = df['MED']
X = df.drop('MED', axis=1)

X_selected = X.filter(['num1', 'num2', 'cate1', 'cate2'])

# from the selected X, further choose categorical only
X_selected_cat = X_selected.filter(['cate1', 'cate2']) # hand selected since some cat var has value 0, 1

# Find the numerical columns, exclude categorical columns
X_num_cols = X_selected.columns[X_selected.dtypes.apply(lambda c: np.issubdtype(c, np.number))] # list of numeric column names, automated here
X_cat_cols = X_selected_cat.columns # list of categorical column names, previously hand-slected

# Split data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_selected, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.5, 
                                                    random_state=567, 
                                                    stratify=y)

# Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([
    ("features", FeatureUnion([
        ('numeric', make_pipeline(Columns(names=X_num_cols),StandardScaler())),
        ('categorical', make_pipeline(Columns(names=X_cat_cols),CateEncoder.BinaryEncoder()))
    ])),
    ('LR_model', LogisticRegression()),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me I should prefer to use `LabelEncoder`.
Just toy example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import sklearn
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn import linear_model

df= pd.DataFrame({ 'y': [10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'a': ['a', 'b','a', 'b','a', 'b','a', 'b' ],
                  'b': ['a', 'b','a', 'b','a', 'b','b', 'b' ],  'c': ['a', 'b','a', 'a','a', 'b','b', 'b' ]})
df
```

I define `class` to select columns

```
class MultiColumn():
    def __init__(self,columns = None):
        self.columns = columns # array of column names to encode

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):                                                           
        return X[self.columns]
```

Now I define class to preprocess with `LabelEncoder`

```
lb = df[['a', 'c']]
class MyLEncoder():

    def transform(self, X, **fit_params):
        enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        enc_data = []
        for i in list(lb.columns):
            encc = enc.fit(lb[i])
            enc_data.append(encc.transform(X[i]))

        return np.asarray(enc_data).T

    def fit_transform(self, X,y=None,  **fit_params):
        self.fit(X,y,  **fit_params)
        return self.transform(X)

    def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):
        return self
```

I use `for-loop` because we can apply `LabelEncoder` just for a single vector.
Pipeline

```
X = df[['a', 'b', 'c']]
y = df['y']
regressor = linear_model.SGDRegressor()

pipeline = Pipeline([
    # Use FeatureUnion to combine the features
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
             # categorical
            ('categorical', Pipeline([
                 ('selector', MultiColumn(columns=['a', 'c'])),
                ('one_hot', MyLEncoder())
            ])),
        ])),
    # Use a regression
    ('model_fitting', linear_model.SGDRegressor()),
])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
pipeline.predict(X)
```

And check for new data

```
new= pd.DataFrame({ 'y': [3, 8], 'a': ['a', 'b' ],'c': ['b', 'a' ], 'b': [3, 6],})
pipeline.predict(new)
```

Similarly, we can do for any method of preprocessing categorical data.

Answer (score 0):

LabelBinarizer and LabelEncoder fit and transform signatures not compatible with Pipeline. So Create your own custom Transformer with the needed signature.

```python
class LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly(LabelBinarizer):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        """this would allow us to fit the model based on the X input."""
        super(LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly, self).fit(X)
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return super(LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly, self).transform(X)

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        return super(LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly, self).fit(X).transform(X)
```